# Работа с полями типа BLOB в приложении WF (C#)

Tags: c#, oracle, база-данных, ado.net

Есть база данных Oracle, из неё необходимо вытащить в datagridview определённые колонки, иными словами, cгруппировать таблицу. Таблица MAIN: в данной таблице интересуют поля NUMBER (номер) и DATETIME (дата/время), с выводом данных полей никаких проблем нет, но интересует также вывод связанной с ней таблицей COMMENT_TABLE, а именно поля COMMENT. С этого момента и начинается основная проблема, а именно с чтения и вывода в datagridview, тип данного поля (COMMENT) BLOB.

```
    data_bin = new DataTable();
da = new OracleDataAdapter("select OR.COMMENT_TABLE.COMMENT from OR.COMMENT_TABLE", conn);
da.Fill(data_bin);
DataColumn column0 = data_bin.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
foreach (DataRow rows in data_bin.Rows)
{
rows[column0] = Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])rows["COMMENT"]);
}

data_bin.Columns.Remove("COMMENT");
DataGridView1.DataSource = data_bin;
```

Данный код вставляет содержимое колонки типа BLOB в datagridview, но остаются нерешёнными два вопроса:
 1. Данный код выводит только непустые строки. Бывает так, что у некоторых объектов нет комментария, и, естественно, это должно также выводится в datagridview, то есть пустые строки не должны быть проигнорированы. Пробовал что-то типа `if(rows.IsNull(column0))`, но не вышло.
 2. В конечном итоге это должна быть сгруппированная таблица, т.е. должен выполняться приведенный ниже запрос и выводиться в datagridview.

```
 "select OR.MAIN.DATETIME, OR.MAIN.NUMBER, OR.COMMENT_TABLE.COMMENT
from OR.MAIN, OR.COMMENT_TABLE
WHERE OR.MAIN.KEY=OR.COMMENT_TABLE.KEY";
```

P.S. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Неужели никто не сталкивался с чем то хотя приблизительно похожим?

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь никакой ORM?